# How can I check if an array contain another array (ANGULAR)?

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, nested

I'd like to know if there's a way to understand if an array contain another array inside him. I ask this question because I'm trying to loop throught two or plus nested arrays but first I need to check this in Angular.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

console.log(Array.isArray(a[0]))
```

You can check this using `Array.isArray` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this can be accomplished, but it depends on the size of the parent array, how deeply nested it's elements are, how does much does performance matter, etc.

If your array only goes one level deep (inner arrays don't contain arrays), you can use these methods:

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3], 'foo', 4, ['foo', 'bar']];

// use .some() to test elements
arr.some((element) => Array.isArray(element));

// returns the index of the first found array, or -1 if no arrays are present
arr.indexOf((element) => Array.isArray(element));
```

[This article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/seven-ways-to-check-existence-of-an-element-in-javascript-array-with-performance-benchmarks-a7f9312c8904) gives a pretty good overview of all options, including the performance of each.